sktime and pycaret conflict: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
I'm trying to make a pull-request to pycaret support the latest sktime, but I have an error that I can´t fix... I don´t know where the mistake in the code...
I tried to contact the pycaret and sktime teams, but they seem to be too busy to pay attention to me, so I came here to see if there is anyone who can help me solve the problem...
Details:
Pull-request: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/pull/4009
Pull-request error: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/actions/runs/9665451003/job/26662574185?pr=4009
traceback:
_______________________ test_pipeline_works_exo[ets] _________________________

load_uni_exo_data_target_missing = (     Consumption    Income  Production   Savings  Unemployment
0       0.615986  0.972261   -2.452700  4.810312      ...01          -0.1
186     0.729598  0.644701    0.474918 -0.572858           0.0

[187 rows x 5 columns], 'Consumption')
model_name = 'ets'

   @pytest.mark.parametrize("model_name", _model_names_for_missing_data)
   def test_pipeline_works_exo(load_uni_exo_data_target_missing, model_name):
       """Tests that the pipeline works for various operations for Univariate
       forecasting with exogenous variables"""
       data, target = load_uni_exo_data_target_missing
   
       exp = TSForecastingExperiment()
       FH = 12
       exp.setup(
           data=data,
           target=target,
           fh=FH,
           numeric_imputation_target="drift",
           numeric_imputation_exogenous="drift",
           enforce_exogenous=False,
       )
   
       assert exp.get_config("y").isna().sum() > 0
       assert exp.get_config("X").isna().sum().sum() > 0
       assert exp.get_config("y_transformed").isna().sum() == 0
       assert exp.get_config("X_transformed").isna().sum().sum() == 0
   
       model = exp.create_model(model_name)
>       preds = exp.predict_model(model)

c:\Users\celes\pycaret\tests\test_time_series_preprocess.py:342: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\pycaret\time_series\forecasting\oop.py:4576: in predict_model
   result = get_predictions_with_intervals(
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\pycaret\utils\time_series\forecasting\__init__.py:110: in get_predictions_with_intervals
   y_pred = forecaster.predict(fh=fh, X=X)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\base\_base.py:448: in predict
   y_pred = self._predict(fh=fh, X=X_inner)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\compose\_pipeline.py:533: in _predict
   X = self._transform(X=X, y=fh)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\forecasting\compose\_pipeline.py:705: in _transform
   X = transformer.transform(X=X, y=y)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\transformations\base.py:612: in transform
   Xt = self._transform(X=X_inner, y=y_inner)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\transformations\compose\_pipeline.py:313: in _transform
   Xt = transformer.transform(X=Xt, y=y)
c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\transformations\base.py:612: in transform
   Xt = self._transform(X=X_inner, y=y_inner)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = Imputer(random_state=1797), X = None, y = None

   def _transform(self, X, y=None):
       """Transform X and return a transformed version.
   
       private _transform containing the core logic, called from transform
   
       Parameters
       ----------
       X : pd.Series or pd.DataFrame
           Data to be transformed
       y : ignored argument for interface compatibility
           Additional data, e.g., labels for transformation
   
       Returns
       -------
       X : pd.Series or pd.DataFrame, same type as X
           transformed version of X
       """
>       X = X.copy()
E       AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

c:\Users\celes\pycaret\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sktime\transformations\series\impute.py:217: AttributeError ```


The error message is telling you that variable X is equal to None; that is to say, it does not have a value. You need to use the debugger to find out why.

Maybe a sktime bug... pycaret gives x as dataset, so it is not None, then i think its a sktime problem...

Well the error message clearly says that it is None, so that is what needs to be fixed.

Can you help find out where the bug is?
Based on the traceback I sent, you can also see the code:
Sktime: https://github.com/sktime/sktime
PyCaret: https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/
I would like to see who is really good at figuring out where the error is... no one has managed so far...

I am sorry, but the only way to find the problem is to use the debugger and trace through the code. The problem with using other people's code is that the person who wrote it is usually the only one who can help you.
